# Android - text overlapping in landscape but not portrait

Tags: java, android, layout

So i have a small issue. When I am in portrait mode and click on an item, the conformation page comes up and its fine. but when you turn it landscape, some text is overwritten but the button. See picture:
[Overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be6r8.png)

However if I click on the item in landscape, its not overlapping. Can anyone see where im going wrong.

Below is the landscape code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_details_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_message_layouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_one_click_message_layout" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_horizontal_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@color/thin_line" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_detalis_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_number_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_message_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_message_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_number_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_message_text"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_message_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/one_click_reservation_number_text"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_number_text"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_name_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_text"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_text"
                    android:text="TEST TEST TEST TES"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_one_click_cancel_reservation_button_tablet_land"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_store_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_time_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_text"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_cancel_reservation_button_tablet_land"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/one_click_cancel_red_button"
                    android:text="@string/one_click_button_cancel_reservation" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_store_details_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_store_details_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/one_click_store_details" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_until_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_details_sent_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_details_sent_text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_mobile_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_mobile_message_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_mobile_message_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_mobile_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_email_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_email_message_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_email_message_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_email_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_cancel_reservation_button_tablet_port"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/one_click_cancel_red_button"
                android:text="@string/one_click_button_cancel_reservation" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_my_account_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_reservation_my_account_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="3"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_one_click_reservation_my_account_text_tablet" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_account_button"
                    style="@style/alternatesmallbutton"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/one_click_my_account" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/fragment_pdp_add_to_trolley_progress_collection"
            style="@style/progress_spinner"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_one_click_horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@color/thin_line" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the WIDTH of the button to WRAP CONTENT and set PADDING for the button to make the button looks larger and set the button to the right of the ID of "Reserved At info text".